Showing QGIS Print layout extent in map as polygon
I would like to display the extent of the various print layouts in the QGIS map as a polygon. To create a kind of overview map where the individual folder sections are shown. I know a manual workaround with geometry by expression:
make_polygon(
    geom_from_wkt(
        'Polygon((xmax ymax, xmax ymin, xmin ymin, xmin ymax, xmax ymax))'
        )
    )

Is there an easier way?

Static export - Processing tool
For a one-off export to an actual layer, use the processing tool 'Print layout map extent to layer'.
To access the processing toolbox press Ctrl+Alt+T, or go to Processing > Processing Toolbox in the top application menu.
You can search for the above tool using the search bar in the toolbox.
To export multiple map extents at a time, click on the Run as Batch Process... button on the bottom left of the processing tool screen (see blue outline below).

Batch process processing tool
If running it as a batch process, you kind of have to manually add a new line for each combination of layout and map name though, I think (not sure how to use expressions to autofill this).
And you can't export to a temporary file, you need to specify a file location and name.
You can autofill the filename based on layout name OR map name (unfortunately, it appears this will be an uuid, not the actual map name).
To have the filename include both layout name AND map name (uuid), you'd need to click the Autofill... button under the Extent column, select Calculate by Expression and use an expression that includes the full file path before and the relevant file extension.
You cannot create new folders using this method so make sure they already exist. If you do want to create new folders on the fly, you may need to use Python instead to programatically iterate folder creation along with the processing tool.
The example below uses 'D:/existing_folder/'||@layout||'_'||@map||'.gpkg'


Dynamic visualisation - Decorations
Alternatively, if you want to visualise the extents on your map dynamically, go to View > Decorations > Layout Extents (tip: the default style for showing the extents is a bit faint; make the line width thicker and increase opacity)
This will show you the extent (and optionally the layout names and map item names) on your main canvas.


If you want to view the extent of the layout in print layout map as an overview map, then

Insert another map in the layout
Go to item properties-> Overview
add an overview, tick "Draw overview" and select the first map in " Map Frame" option


